# Phonegap Plugman iOS - ERROR: Plugin not found

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I used Plugman to install a plugin like so:

> plugman install --platform iOS --project
>   /Users/User/Documents/Projects/MyProject --plugin
>   https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git

and Plugman says that installation is successful.

Yet, when building the project, xCode output says:

> CDVPlugin class CDVSplashScreen (pluginName: splash screen) does not
>   exist.
>
> [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 1.785994ms
>
> CDVPlugin class CDVSplashScreen (pluginName: SplashScreen) does not
>   exist.
>
> ERROR: Plugin 'SplashScreen' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check
>   your plugin mapping in config.xml.

The second error might be because I am trying to call the Splashscreen plugin with javascript but I do have SplashScreen files in two locations in my project:

MyProject/cordova/plugins/org.apache.cordova.core.splashscreen/

and

MyProject/MyProject.xcode/plugins/org.apache.cordova.core.splashscreen/CDVSplashScreen.h
MyProject/MyProject.xcode/plugins/org.apache.cordova.core.splashscreen/CDVSplashScreen.m

MyProject, thus, looks like this:

- MyProject/cordova
- MyProject/CordovaLib
- MyProject/MyProject
- MyProject/SpendToday.xcodeproj
- MyProject/www

I can't install any other plugin without the same problems. Does anyone have any ideas?

I'm using Phonegap 3.0 without CLI (upgraded from Phonegap 2.4)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In xcode, I navigated to MyProject/MyProject/Plugins

and found

- /CDVSplashScreen.h
- /CDVSplashScreen.m
- /CDVInAppBrowser.h
- /CDVInAppBrowser.m

right there in the root. So I chose to delete (only the references), the re-added the SplashScreen folder, which was in the file system.

Now the folder looks like this:

- /org.apache.cordova.core.splashscreen/CDVSplashScreen.h
- /org.apache.cordova.core.splashscreen/CDVSplashScreen.m
- /CDVInAppBrowser.h
- /CDVInAppBrowser.m

and now SplashScreen works!

Comment: Had the same issue with the inapp browser. Had even tried removing the plugin and adding it back with no success. Followed these steps to remove it from the xcode project and add it back and then it worked great! Thanks!

Comment: Having to remove the files and add the WHOLE folder manually did the trick. Boy what a nightmare, thanks for that help. This was on xCode 6.0.1 FWIW.